# Implement 2 columns on mobile - Woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would love to show 2 columns of products in my Woocomerce active shop.
I use a child theme based on 'Shopisle', and I'm not really sure what is the best way to make it happen. A CSS-only solution would be viable? Will it behave properly, without any bugs?

I believe the theme uses Bootstrap as a foundation, but I'm not 100% certain about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve this?

Comment: Hi, @lumio!

I've tried to style the CSS using the following rules:

.woocommerce ul.products li.product {
width: 50%;
margin: 0;
}

The result for it is this: http://imgur.com/Etstat8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want - since you gave almost no code example here.

But usually what I'd do is using a flexbox:

```
.wrapper-of-all-products {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.product {
  width: 49%; // just to be sure there is a gap
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Of course you need to change the classnames. I have no idea how they are called.

Comment: Wow, @lumio!
I haven't updated the CSS to 'debug' it yet, but in the preview, it is working like a charm. The 'flex' solution is just amazing, I already knew about it but it never came to my mind to apply it there.

I will make the changes live and then report if everything is straight up! Thanks again!

Comment: Well, I've tested the code on the live website and it is presenting some issues, as usual. Is it smart to control these settings using media queries for mobile displays? Or should I make it 'mobile-first' and then scale the queries up? I was thinking to set as a 767px limit to the rules be applied or something like it.

Comment: That's up to you. I think it depends where you main target is usually at. If they usually use their mobile phone or not

Comment: Thanks a lot, again, @lumio!
I've taken this night to implement the code and it's rocking solid, as it seems. I had to debug many things, such as the buttons, which happened to cause some issues, such as occupying the whole container and appearing weird, but it was a slice of pie to fix it all! I could only make it due to your swift 'display: flex' approach. That fixed my problem and that also widened my mind to future projects! Thank you so much, and I hope this thread can also help other people

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather use a backend approach. Grids and lists are generated by a woocommerce template file called:

```
woocommerce/templates/content-product.php
```

Its very common that themes already modify this file due its own styling but they are all doing pretty much the same thing;

```
  <li <?php wc_product_class(); ?> ></li>
```

If you aren't using a theme and you are customizing woocommerce files, then you could add grid classes to wc_product_class function, something like:

```
   wc_product_class("col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-xl-4");
```

Work around these columns classes to see which one works best for you, in that case is Large screens 4 columns, medium 3 column, small 2 columns, extra small 2 columns.

Now usually themes are already updating this file, so you should override their template in its Child Theme, this is very important so you don't loose changes if the theme gets updated. In my case, I always start with my own child theme, and modify everything in there so its even more organize.

This is a sample from a theme overriding content-product.php:

```
 $classes[] = Lezada_Helper::get_grid_item_class( apply_filters( 'lezada_shop_products_columns',
    array(
        'xs' => 1,
        'sm' => 2,
        'md' => 3,
        'lg' => 4,
        'xl' => get_option( 'woocommerce_catalog_columns', 4 ),
    ) ) );

$classes[] = apply_filters( 'lezada_product_style', 'product-style--' . lezada_get_option( 'product_style' ) );

$other_classes = apply_filters( 'lezada_shop_products_classes', '' );
$classes[]     = $other_classes;

?>

<div <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>
```

In this case you can see the variable $classes. By updating the array where it shows the column type, by selecting the number of columns then I can easily choose the amount of columns per view. Now this is very unique from this theme, every theme is different but I wanted to give you an example.

This solution will definitely work always! No worries for cached css or whatever other problem you might encounter in the future because its done the proper way in the backend.

Best,